Using and Creating SAS Macro in the same step
The macro below (the into :&count is causing issues). Although it doesn't show an error, later when I call salescount, it's clear the macro was not assigned properly "Apparent symbolic reference salescount was not resolved." Is there a way to fix the macro so I don't have to go back writing out the full proc sql entry each time I need it?
%macro counts (variable1, count, dataname);

proc sql;
select count(distinct &variable1) into :&count trimmed
from &dataname;
quit;
%mend counts;

%counts(userid, salescount, customers)



When a macro variable does not already exist, creating a macro variable inside of a macro will create a local macro variable. You need to declare it as global first to use it outside of the macro:
%macro counts (variable1, count, dataname);
    %global &count;

    proc sql;
        select count(distinct &variable1) into :&count trimmed
        from &dataname;
    quit;
%mend counts;


When a macro variable does not already exist ...  It does not have to be in the GLOBAL symbol table. It could exist in the local symbol table of any macro that is active when the %counts() macro was called.

I believe the correct way to make a macro variable global is %global count; otherwise, you'll make the resolved variable global.

The second argument of the macro of the defines the name of the macro variable that is populated by proc SQL. Since we don't want count itself to be global, we want its resolution to be global, so we specify %global &count to set the resolution of &count to be global. If we specify %global count, the macro variable count will be global every time the macro is run.

Agree with Stu's description of why to use %global &count.  In this case if you use %global count you will get an error when you execute the macro, because you can't create a global macro variable COUNT when a local macro variable COUNT already exists (because it's a macro parameter).

@StuSztukowski. I get it :)
